# JavaCC: Matching an empty string

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, javacc

I am having trouble with ambiguous tokens. My grammar defines two productions, a numeric constant of the form **2e3** or **100e1**, and identifiers of the form **abc** or **uvw123**.

The problem is that **e1** is a valid identifier, but also constitutes part of a numeric constant. So for example, if my input consists of **2e3**, it will be tokenized as a number followed by an identifier (**2** + **e3**), which is not what I want.

I could match numeric constants by writing a more general regex that includes the **e**, instead of leaving that to a grammar production, but then the token value/image will require parsing to separate the integer and exponent parts, which is not what I want. This is not what I want.

I have attempted to solve this problem by using tokenizer states. Because an identifier cannot begin with a digit, a digit must indicate the beginning of a numeric constant, and so I transition to **STATE_NUMBER**. In this state I define an **e** token to refer to the exponent part of the numeric constant. I then have a "catch everything else" token, with the intention of transitioning back to the **DEFAULT** state. In the default state, an **e** would been matched by the identifier regex.

```
TOKEN : {
  < digit_sequence: (["0"-"9"])+ > : STATE_NUMBER
}

<STATE_NUMBER> TOKEN : {
  < exponent_prefix: "e" >
}

<STATE_NUMBER> MORE : {
  < end_number: ~[] > : DEFAULT
}

TOKEN : {
  < identifier: ["a"-"z"] (["0"-"9","a"-"z"])* >
}
```

This does not work as expected. The character matched by the **MORE** token appears to be discarded instead of becoming the first character of an identifier.

I'd like to know how to write a proper grammar for this. I would prefer it if I did not have to use any inline Java code.

Comment: What if you define a digit_sequence as digits plus (optionally) an e and more digits? Something like (["0"-"9"]+(e["0"-"9"]+)?), so you get the number with only one state... would it work?

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want because the token value/image will require parsing to separate the integer and exponent parts.

Comment: I changed the title as I didn't think this had anything to with ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `< end_number: ~[] > : DEFAULT` matches any character that is not an `e`. What you want to match instead is an empty string.  Try

```
< end_number: "" > : DEFAULT
```

I think the following will work.

```
TOKEN : {
  < (["0"-"9"])+ > : STATE_NUMBER0
}

<STATE_NUMBER0> TOKEN : {
  < "e" > : STATE_NUMBER1
}

<STATE_NUMBER0> MORE : {
  < number_without_exponent: "" > : DEFAULT
}

<STATE_NUMBER1> MORE : {
   < number_with_exponent: (["0"-"9"])+ > : DEFAULT
}
```

This makes  `123e`  an error, as is `123edf`. If you don't want these to be errors, you can get away with one fewer states.

```
TOKEN : {
  < (["0"-"9"])+ > : STATE_NUMBER
}

<STATE_NUMBER> TOKEN : {
  < number_with_exponent: "e" (["0"-"9"])+ > : DEFAULT
}

<STATE_NUMBER> MORE : {
  < number_without_exponent: "" > : DEFAULT
}
```

This makes `123e` a `number_without_exponent` followed by an `identifier`, "e". If you'd prefer that it be just a `number_without_exponent`, change the last `+` to a `*`.